# In Python I want to code so that if user types a word that my list has more than once, both of the strings in the list get taken out

Tags: python, list, input, subtraction

I want to have a list that is like ["King S", "King H", "Ace S", "4 C"]
and then when asked for user input on what card to drop, if the user writes king, both kings will be taken out of the list.

I have just started coding and so far I have made the code so that if you type a specific card like "King H", it will be taken out of the list.

```
dropCard = input()
dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
while dropCardCapital not in pOneCards:
    print("You do not have the card " + dropCardCapital + ", please type a card that you have.")
    dropCard = input()
    dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
if dropCardCapital in pOneCards:
        print("You dropped " + dropCardCapital)
DCCC = Counter([dropCardCapital])
pOneCards = set(pOneCardsCounter - DCCC)
pOneCardsCounter = Counter(pOneCards)
```

pOneCards is the list in which I want the cards to be taken out of. It checks if the input is in pOneCards and if it is using Counters it subtracts your input from pOneCards list. What I want to happen though is that if your input is king and the list has two kings both get subtracted.

I am also okay with instead of making each card King H/King S just have four "King" and not specify the color or suit it is.

Answer (score 0):

I made function `remove_card()`, where you can specify card by only value, or with value AND color:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["King S", "King H", "Ace S", "4 C"]

def remove_card(card, lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    s = ' '.join(lst).split()
    for value, color in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]):
        d[value.lower()].append(color.lower())

    value, color = map(str.lower, card.split() if ' ' in card else (card, ''))

    dropped = []
    if value in d and color == '' and len(d[value]) > 1:
        # remove all cards of certain value only if color is unspecified and we have
        # more than one card of this value
        dropped = [(value + ' ' + v).title() for v in d[value]]
        del d[value]
    elif value in d and color != '' and color in d[value]:
        # color is specified and we have this card, remove it
        dropped = [(value + ' ' + color).title()]
        d[value].remove(color)

    # convert back defaultdict to list
    return [(k + ' ' + c).title() for k, v in d.items() for c in v], dropped

print('Initial list: ', lst)
lst, dropped = remove_card('ace', lst)  # no card is removed - we have only one Ace
print('After trying to remove "ace": ', lst)
print('We dropped: ', dropped)
lst, dropped = remove_card('ace s', lst)    # Ace S is removed - color is specified
print('After trying to remove "ace s": ', lst)
print('We dropped: ', dropped)
lst, dropped = remove_card('king', lst) # all 'kings' are removed, because we have more than one king
print('After trying to remove "king": ', lst)
print('We dropped: ', dropped)
```

Prints:

```
Initial list:  ['King S', 'King H', 'Ace S', '4 C']
After trying to remove "ace":  ['King S', 'King H', 'Ace S', '4 C']
We dropped:  []
After trying to remove "ace s":  ['King S', 'King H', '4 C']
We dropped:  ['Ace S']
After trying to remove "king":  ['4 C']
We dropped:  ['King S', 'King H']
```